# IntelliJ: How to change module to be opened within terminal?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have multiple modules opened in IntelliJ, let's say

- Module A
- Module B
- **Module C**

When I open the internal terminal it always starts at **Module C**, but I want to change this behaviour depending on my current task.

Is it possible to somehow configure that the terminals starts at **Module A**?

Comment: Switch code in module C with code in module A?

Comment: Why don't you create a symlink in module c to module a, then issue a simple cd command when the terminal opens? It's not perfect, but it's minimal work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also possible to just Drag&Drop the folder into the terminal. After that a new terminal with the folders location will be openend.

[image: Drag&Drop]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible for now. [Related request.](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117340)

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I wanted to hear, but I expected something like this ;)